# error using snowball in lucene

Tags: java, lucene, snowball

I have added lucene 3.5.0 and when i added a seperate jar for the snowball analyzer i get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballAnalyzer.setOverridesTokenStreamMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballAnalyzer.<init>(SnowballAnalyzer.java:46)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballAnalyzer.<init>(SnowballAnalyzer.java:61)
at lucene.similarity.rank_stop.main(rank_stop.java:34)
```

My code includes :

```
Analyzer analyzers = new SnowballAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30,"English",StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET); 

private static String analyze(String text) throws IOException {
        int i=0; 
        String result="" ; 
        String[] term = new String[100] ; 
        TokenStream stream = analyzers.reusableTokenStream("contents",new StringReader(text));
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        while (stream.incrementToken()) {      
            term[i] = charTermAttribute.toString();  
            result+=term[i]+" " ; 
            i++; 
        } 
        return result;  
    }
}
  line2 = analyze(line2); // here line2 is a string that has to be analyzed
```

Can somebody help me out with this ?

Comment: Looks like your Snowball and Lucene versions are incompatible, but I don't know anything specific about the version history to help you find a pair that will work together.

Comment: Yes. Can somebody suggest a snowball version that matches lucene 3.5.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help .. I got a compatible version ... [This](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers/3.5.0) is it